# How to unblock chrome extensions on public computers

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

All the computers in my University have now new Google chrome installed on them. The problem is that they disabled all the extensions. When I try to install an extension from the store it just gets stuck on "searching" and doesn't install anything.

I also tried to manually install (Adblock), but that doesn't work.

Is there a way to unlock the chrome extensions (or at least to install adblock)?

Comment: What does it say when you try to install Adblock manually?

Comment: When I do it through the chrome web store it keeps writing checking. when I manually download the .crx thing it just doesn't open it...